# binding options: in a select fails to pick the correct value on init

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following select:

```
<select data-bind=" options: states, 
                    optionsText: 'acronym', 
                    optionValue: 'stateId', 
                    value: state">
</select>
```

ViewModel and dependencies:

```
    function State(state) {
        var self = this;
        self.stateId = ko.observable(state.StateId);
        self.acronym = ko.observable(state.Acronym);
    }

    function AddressViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.cities = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.states = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.zipcode = ko.observable();
        self.city = ko.observable();
        self.state = ko.observable();
        self.stateHard = ko.observable();
        self.address = ko.observable();
        self.addressNumber = ko.observable();
        self.address2 = ko.observable();
        self.town = ko.observable();
        self.phoneNumber = ko.observable();
        self.mobileNumber = ko.observable();

        self.state.subscribe(function () {
            self.UpdateCities();
        });

        self.UpdateCities = function () {
            if (self.state())
                $.getJSON("/api/v1/address/cities/" + self.state().stateId(), 
                          function (data) {
                    self.cities($.map(data, function (item) { 
                                                    return new City(item) }));
                });
        }

   $.getJSON("/api/v1/user/address/", function (data) {
                    self.zipcode(data.zipcode);
                    self.city(new City(data.city));
                    self.state(new State(data.state));
                    self.address(data.address);
                    self.addressNumber(data.addressNumber);
                    self.address2(data.address2);
                    self.town(data.town);
                    self.phoneNumber(data.phoneNumber);
                    self.mobileNumber(data.mobileNumber);

            $.getJSON("/api/v1/address/states", function (data) {
                self.states($.map(data, function (item) { 
                                                 return new State(item) }));
            });
        });
    }
```

But when I involke `ko.applyBindings(new AddressViewModel());` the `AVM.state` loses its original value, although that value is in the list.

I already tried to invert the `getJSON` order (states before state and vice versa) but nothing new happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a few issues going on here.

1. You spelled the `optionsValue` value wrong in your data-bind section.
2. If you spelled the `optionsValue` option correctly, when you choose an item from the drop-down, you will be writing `State.stateId` to `AVM.state`; however in your initialisation call you create an object: `self.state(new State(data.state))`.  You can't expect that to work; you're initialising with an object reference but updating with a literal value.
3. If you spelled the `optionsValue` option *incorrectly* and would like to keep it working this way - first up delete `optionValue` so you don't get confused.  Next - be aware that an *object* will be written to `AVM.state`.  The object equivalence testing is done by *reference*, not by deep-inspection of the objects values.  You would need to pull a reference from `AVM.states` and write it to `AVM.state`.  Something like this:

   ```
   // Use the data.state.StateId to find the correct state from the states list.
   self.state(ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.states(), function (s) {
       return s.stateId() === data.state.StateId;
   }));
   ```

The order of initialisation is important **IF** the databinding occurs before you've finished all your AJAX calls.  If databinding occurs **before** all ajax calls are complete the following is the sequence of events:

1. AJAX calls for state/states started.
2. `ko.applyBindings(AVM);` is called, options: binds against the empty `AVM.states` list.
3. AJAX for /api/v1/user/address completes, `AVM.state` is set.
4. options: binding notes that `AVM.state` is not in `AVM.states` and writes NULL to `AVM.state`.
5. AJAX for /api/v1/address/states completes, `AVM.states` is set.
6. options: binding now uses `AVM.states` to update the dropdown with options, and by default the first one is selected.
7. You look at the UI wondering "what happened?"

I've attached references to a couple JSFiddles showing two approaches to the problem.

Version 1 - Using `optionsValue` in the data-bind call:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lam42/1/

Version 2 - Removing `optionsValue` and using object references:
http://jsfiddle.net/sFW4j/

Comment: actually i'm not using optionsValue. I put it cause i did not what else to do.

Comment: my code seems pretty close from what you did in Version 2, except from the way you inits the state. I'll have a deeper look on your solutions to see if i find any other difference. Thank you for your very detailed answer.

Comment: Aah ok - in that case you'll only need to pull the reference from your states list using that ko.utils.arrayFirst call I included in the answer above.  Glad to have helped.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a function and move the code block $.getJSON("/api/v1/user/address/",..  inside the function. And then, call that function after invoking ko.applyBindings(new AddressViewModel());.